# Two Annotation Pins at a time in MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I successfully implemented `MKMapVIew` and a single annotation on my Map. I am not able to represent two postitions simultaneously. I am using `MKMapViewDelegate` method :

`mapView:viewForAnnotation:`

Can someone look into this thing.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
region.center.latitude = 22.569722 ;
region.center.longitude = 88.369722;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.1f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.1f;
MKCoordinateRegion anotherRegion = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
anotherRegion.center.latitude = 28.38 ;
anotherRegion.center.longitude = 77.12;
anotherRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 90.0f;
anotherRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 90.0f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

[mapView setDelegate:self];

DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
ann.title = @" Kolkata";
ann.subtitle = @"Mahatma Gandhi Road"; 
ann.coordinate = region.center; 
[mapView addAnnotation:ann];
DisplayAnotherMap *annMap = [[DisplayAnotherMap alloc] init]; 
annMap.title = @" New Delhi";
annMap.subtitle = @"Shahdara"; 
annMap.coordinate = anotherRegion.center; 
[mapView addAnnotations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:annMap,ann,nil]];
}
```

*This will fulfill the requirement for you! ...:)*

Answer (score 0):

The method mapView:viewForAnnotation: is just for the view of a the annotations, eg. the colour of the pin and the title label etc. If you want to show multiple annotations you should alloc and init the all with the required positions. For example, you could create a .plist with all the coordinates and the in for cycle just add them.

**EDIT**
This is a sample code, taken from somewhere. You must alloc and init all anotations.

```
-(void)loadDummyPlaces{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    NSMutableArray *tempPlaces=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {

        MyPlace *place=[[MyPlace alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self RandomFloatStart:42.0 end:47.0],[self RandomFloatStart:14.0 end:19.0])];
        [place setCurrentTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Place %d title",i]];
        [place setCurrentSubTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Place %d subtitle",i]];
        [place addPlace:place];
        [tempPlaces addObject:place];
        [place release];

    }
    places=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempPlaces];

    [tempPlaces release];
}
```

Comment: I have instantiated the MKAnnotation delegated class. And added the annotation on my mapVIew. But just one is visible to me. I can't see other.